# Typedoc Error: Tried to set an option (mode) that was not declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, typedoc

I installed typedoc:

```
npm install typedoc --save-dev
```

Then added typedocOptions into tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // ...some lines there
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
  "typedocOptions": {
    "mode": "modules",
    "out": "docs"
  }
}
```

Then I do:

```
npx typedoc --out docs src/index.ts
```

And get the error:

```
Error: Tried to set an option (mode) that was not declared.
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `mode` option has been removed as of v0.20.0 as described in the [release notes](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/releases/tag/v0.20.0).
The full list of options can be seen in the [documentation](https://typedoc.org/options/).

Related issue [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1447)